# Is there a way to pass the object of two different class in one variable in different conditions

Tags: swift

I have two classes for `language` that I want to use at run-time in different conditions.

I want to get both the class's objects in one single variable, as per the condition. However, I am getting an error.

```swift
var constantCL = LanguageEnglish()
if languageType == Constants.LoginParameters.LANGUAGE_CODE_ENGLISH {
    constantCL = LanguageEnglish()
} else {
    constantCL = LanguageHindi()
}
```

Getting this error on `constantCL = LanguageHindi()` in my `else`:

> Cannot assign value of type 'LanguageHindi' to type 'LanguageEnglish'

Screenshot of error:

[image: Please check the screenshot for more clarification:]

Comment: You can but you need to make sure the variable `constantCL` is a type that can hold both LanguageEnglish and LanguageHindi types. For instance, are they both subclasses of the same class? Is there a protocol both conform to?

Comment: can you show the definitions for LanguageHindi and LanguageEnglish?

Comment: Here it is: `class LanguageEnglish: NSObject` and `class LanguageEnglish: NSObject`

Answer (score 2):

This is an expected behavior since your language is an actual class, instead of something a bit more flexible.

Possible solutions:

**Use a superclass for your languages, e.g.**

```
class LanguageEnglish: Language { }
class LanguageHindi: Language { }

var constantCL: Language = LanguageEnglish()
```

**Use a protocol instead**, and implement it in your language classes (almost the same as above, difference is in implementation and declaration):

```
class LanguageEnglish: Language { }
class LanguageHindi: Language { }

var constantCL: Language = LanguageEnglish()
```

Or maybe **use an enum** to represent your languages, or a similar more elegant construct if it suits your needs:

```
enum Language {
    case english
    case hindi

    // Other useful stuff
}

var constantCL: Language = .english
constantCL = .hindi
```